# vue.js dynamic component state

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a multi-step layout managed with a dynamic component

```js
<keep-alive>
    <component :is="actualStep" :status.sync="status"></component>
</keep-alive>
<button @click.prevent="prevStep">Prev</button>
<button @click.prevent="nextStep" :disabled="!status">Next</button>
```

`status` value is used to monitor the actual component status, updating its value to true or false depending on component's internal validation process, and allowing (or not) to move to next step. As an example, a component will change status to true only if all required fields are filled.

`status` is also changed to an initial value when component is initiated. Some components change it to true (as they don't make any validation) and some change it to the validation process result.

```js
mounted() {
    this.$emit('update:status', this.isValid);  // isValid is a computed
}
```

However this is only happening once when the component is mounted (I guess because of keep-alive). I would need to do this every time the dynamic component changes to the `actualStep`. How can this be done? or is it a better way to manage dynamic components' status?

Comment: Try `activated()` instead of `mounted()`. The `activated` hook will fire whenever the dynamic component changes.

Comment: Great! I was looking for lifecycle hooks and just found the standard ones. Thanks.
Anyway, is there a better way to manage a multistep status?